# Writing and reading a binary file

Tags: c, post-quantum-cryptography

I am trying to to write `crypt->public_key->data` into a binary file. If I use size of `sizeof(unsigned int)` as the second argument in `fwrite()`, it works. However, it is declared as `unsigned short *` type in the header file. I am not sure why it behaves as such. Also, I face problem while writing public key and reading them as well. Although I use the size of the exactly same type in the `fwrite()` and `fread()`.

Edit: It appears that the size of my crypt->public_key->data is incorrect as pointed out by usr2564301.

*I'm not sure whether I need to cite the source of this code or not. But I'll add the URL here: https://github.com/Varad0612/The-McEliece-Cryptosystem

Code from a matrix.h

```
typedef struct matrix
{
   int rows;             //number of rows.
   int cols;             //number of columns.
   unsigned short *data;
}*bin_matrix;
```

This is the code from mceliece.c

```
//Initialize the mceliece cryptosystem
mcc mceliece_init(int n0, int p, int w, int t)
{
    FILE *publicKey, *privateKey;
    mcc crypt;  
    crypt = (mcc)safe_malloc(sizeof(struct mceliece));  
    //crypt->code = qc_mdpc_init(n0, p, w, t);
    //crypt->public_key = generator_matrix(crypt->code);

    //printf("%d\n",crypt->public_key->rows);
    //printf("%d\n",crypt->public_key->cols);

    //Write public key into a binary file
    /*publicKey = fopen("PublicKey.bin", "wb");
    privateKey = fopen("PrivateKey.bin", "wb");

    if(privateKey != NULL){
        fwrite(crypt->code->row, n0*p*sizeof(unsigned short), n0 * p, privateKey);
        fclose(privateKey); 
    }
    else{
        printf("Unable to write private key\n");    
    }

    //Write public key into a binary file
    if(publicKey != NULL){
        fwrite(crypt->public_key->data, p*p*n0*sizeof(unsigned short), crypt->public_key->rows*crypt->public_key->cols, publicKey);
        fclose(publicKey);
    }
    else{
        printf("Unable to write public key\n");
    }*/

    //Read private key from a binary file
    crypt->code = (mdpc)safe_malloc(sizeof(struct qc_mdpc));
    crypt->code->n0 = n0;
    crypt->code->p = p;
    crypt->code->w = w;
    crypt->code->t = t;
    crypt->code->n = n0 * p;
    crypt->code->r = p;
    crypt->code->k = (n0 - 1) * p;
    crypt->code->row = (unsigned short*)calloc(n0 * p, sizeof(unsigned short));
    privateKey = fopen("PrivateKey.bin", "rb");
    if(privateKey != NULL){
        fread(crypt->code->row, p*n0*sizeof(unsigned short), p*n0, privateKey);
        fclose(privateKey); 
    }
    else
        printf("Unable to read private key\n");

    //Read public key from a binary file
    /*crypt->public_key = (bin_matrix)safe_malloc(sizeof(struct matrix));
    crypt->public_key->data = (unsigned short*)safe_malloc(p*p*n0*sizeof(unsigned short));
    crypt->public_key->rows = p;
    crypt->public_key->cols = n0*p; 
    publicKey = fopen("PublicKey.bin", "rb");
    if(publicKey != NULL){
        fread(crypt->public_key->data, p*p*n0*sizeof(unsigned short), crypt->public_key->rows*crypt->public_key->cols, publicKey);
        fclose(publicKey);  
    }
    else{
        printf("Unable to read public key\n");
    }*/

    printf("Successful\n");
    //printf("mceliece generated...\n");
    return crypt;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned int)` is a constant size, supplied by your compiler. However, you *do not know* if the amount of data at `->data` is that large – you cannot derive the allocated size from a pointer. Presumably, you need to calculate its actual size from the other elements in that struct.

Comment: @SteveSummit: that gets multiplied by the earlier `sizeof(unsigned int)`. Which cannot be correct – it should probably be `sizeof(unsiged short)`. Mind, the OP is vague about what is not working. Too little data gets written? Too much?

Comment: @Lance Multiplying by `sizeof(unsigned short)` should be correct, since that's the size of the underlying data.  Multiplying by `sizeof(unsigned int)` should be quite wrong, and should not work.  Can you be a little more clear on how it fails when you use `unsigned short`?  Are `crypt->public_key->rows` and `->cols` set properly at the point where you call `fwrite`?  (Presumably the code which sets them is down in `generator_matrix()`.)

Comment: @SteveSummit I get a decoding failure message which is located in the decode() in qc_mdpc.c. I think that the 'crypt->public_key->rows' and '->cols' are correct as I didn't modify anything from this part in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusion in our reading statement:

```
fread(crypt->code->row, p*n0*sizeof(unsigned short), p*n0, privateKey);
```

This will attempt to read `p*n0` elements, each with a size of `p*n0*sizeof(unsigned short)` bytes. If the file is not larger than the allocated size, you will be lucky as `fread` would not attempt to write beyond the end of the allocated block.

You should instead write:

```
size_t nread = fread(crypt->code->row, sizeof(unsigned short), p * n0, privateKey);
if (nread == p * n0) {
    /* private key was read successfully */
} else {
    /* file is too short, only nread words were read */
}
```

Comment: `fread` does not guarantee to read as much data as requested, even if there is that much data in the file.

Comment: @zwol: actually, it does: C11 7.21.8.1p3 *The` fread` function returns the number of elements successfully read, which may be less than `nmemb` if a read error or end-of-file is encountered. If `size` or `nmemb` is zero, `fread` returns zero and the contents of the array and the state of the stream remain unchanged.* You must be referring to the unix `read` system call which may return a short count for multiple reasons even if the file has data available.

Comment: Your interpretation is plausible, but I'm not aware of _any_ implementation of `fread` that loops internally if `read` returns a short count, so as a practical matter users of `fread` must be prepared to handle short reads.

Comment: @zwol: really? I just looked up the glibc and found the proper loop in the internal function `_IO_default_xsgetn`. The glibc is quite a piece of work to untangle. The newlibc has the loop too in the internal function `_fread_r`. The Apple libc, derived from BSD also has the proper loop in `__fread` and `__fread0`. You must be referring to ancient or exotic implementations. If `fread` were to stop at some random location, there would be no way to restart it properly. It makes sense that it can only fail because of end-of-file or read-error, just like `getc`.

Comment: I admit to being a relic of the 1990s but I am still very surprised to learn that current `fread` implementations do contain a loop.  "Never set the `size` parameter to anything other than 1" was stock advice when I learned C, precisely so you _could_ restart.

Comment: @zwol: We have this in common (I may even be 10 or 20 years older) and I do concede C programmers should be wary of the peculiarities of their target system. Many systems do not support C99 properly yet, It took Microsoft 16 years to make this move, but I have not seen a bogus implementation of `fread` and `fwrite` in a long time. I'm curious to be proven wrong.

Comment: @chqrlie I've changed the code as you suggested. But I don't understand why my size should be `p*n0*sizeof(unsigned short)` in fwrite() but `sizeof(unsigned short)` in fread(). If I change the size in fwrite() to `sizeof(unsigned short)`, then I'll get a decoding failure.

Comment: @Lance: The sizes should be consistent between `fread`, `fwrite` and `calloc`. You allocate `n0 * p * sizeof(short)` bytes with `calloc(n0 * p, sizeof(unsigned short))`, you should write the same amount of data with `fwrite(crypt->code->row, sizeof(unsigned short), p * n0, privateKey);` and read it back with `fread(crypt->code->row, sizeof(unsigned short), p * n0, privateKey);`.  Your current code attempts to read **much** more data, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @chqrlie When I do `fwrite(crypt->code->row, sizeof(unsigned short), p * n0, privateKey);`, I get a decoding error.

Comment: @Lance: do you encode and decode on the same computer? You only posted a fragment of code, I cannot tell you what is incorrect in the rest of the application.

Comment: @chqrlie I'm using the code from here: https://github.com/Varad0612/The-McEliece-Cryptosystem. I didn't change anything except trying to read and write keys in mceliece.c

Comment: @Lance: the package in reference does not use `fread` nor `fwrite`, it uses a text based interface to read and write the data. Your changes require a better understanding of the innerworkings of this software.